# How can access running app in my computer localhost inside kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

i have a question about kubernetes networking.

My working senario:

- I have a Jenkins  container my localhost and this container up and running. Inside Jenkins, i have a job. Access jenkins , i use "http://localhost:8080" url. (jenkins is not runing inside kubernetes)
- My flask app, trigger the Jenkins job with this command:

> ```
>     @app.route("/create",methods=["GET","POST"])
> def create():
>     
>     if request.method =="POST":
>         dosya_adi=request.form["sendmail"]
>         server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:8080/', username='my-user-name', password='my-password')
>         server.build_job('jenkins_openvpn', {'FILE_NAME': dosya_adi}, token='my-token')
> ```

- Then, i did Dockerize this flask app. My image name is: "jenkins-app"
- If i run this command, everythings perfect:

> `docker run -it --network="host" --name=jenkins-app jenkins-app`

But i want to do samething with kubernetes. For that i wrote this yml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pod
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: jenkins-app
    image: jenkins-app:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5000
```

- With this yml file, i access the flask app using port 5000. While i want to trigger jenkins job, i get an error like this: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError

Would you suggest if there is a way to do this with Kubernetes?

Comment: You can try with `kubectl port-forward <name of the pod> 31145:5000`. If that doesn't work, you swap the 5000 with 8080 (I'm never really sure which one is visible from the outside :)).

Comment: Host networking seems totally unnecessary here.  In a Kubernetes context, it might not work the way you expect, and it might very reasonably be forbidden by the cluster operator.  Can you configure the Jenkins location to be something else in the calling application, and make it visible from Kubernetes via normal means (an Ingress, or a NodePort or LoadBalancer-type Service)?

Comment: @DavidMaze i try but didn't work

Comment: @ennur What exactly did you try? And why did it not work: errors/anything? Also answer below has one of the way to expose the pod as service with `ClusterIP`. If your app is running on local machine and not in cluster, then you need to expose service as `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` (depends on cluster you're using)

Comment: @moonkotte i tried to change jenkins IP in the flask app. Same as the this error requests.exceptions.ConnectionError. I will try using nodeport. Is necessery to add an endpoint for reach jenkins? Will nodeport automaticaly do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create an endpoint.yml file and add in this file below commands, this solve my problem:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
    name: jenkins-server
subsets:
    - addresses:
        - ip: my-ps-ip
    ports:
        - port: 8080
```

Then, I change this line in my flask app like this:

```py
server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://my-ps-ip:8080/', username='my-user-name', password='my-password')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First you expose your Jenkins server:

`kubectl expose pod jenkins-pod --port=8080 --target-port 5000`

Then you check the existence of the service:

`kubectl get svc jenkins-pod -o yaml`

Use it for your Flask app to connect to your Jenkins server via this service:

`... jenkins.Jenkins('http://jenkins-pod.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/...'`

Note the assumption is you run everything in default namespace, otherwise change the "default" to your namespace.